# My code works in Jupyter Notebook but not as Python script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am running a code properly in Jupyter notebook. After exporting it with nbconvert, I've got a python script.
However, when I run the script, an error *"Import Error: No module named jetcam.csi_camera"* occurs in the following line:

```
from jetcam.csi_camera import CSICamera
```

I am new to Jupyter lab so, in general, what are the necessary steps to run a py script from the Jupyter notebook (.ipynb)?

Comment: You need to make sure to run the script using the same python interpreter that your Jupyter notebook uses, or at least that the necessary packages are installed. I.e. if you run `pip freeze` where you run your script, do you see that package installed there?

Comment: Yes, I can see the package installed

Comment: if you run `which pip` and `which python`, are they both indicating the same python installation ?

Comment: both commands returned nothing. However, following with the approach, if I execute print(python_version()) in the Jupyter code, I've got the 3.6.9 version. And If I execute the command python --version from the console, I've got the 2.7.17...

Comment: Indeed you do not have the same version in Jupyter and on your computer. You should install Python 3 on your computer, Python 2 is obsolete since January 2020.

Comment: So, Python 3.6 was already installed, but the version remained at 2.7. After setting it to 3.6, this error is solved. $ sudo update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pip in your command prompt/terminal to install it to python